# In a C/C++ program, how can I write bold text in the terminal?

Tags: c++, c, console, formatting

is it possible to format the console output, like writing in bold, of a C/C++ program? I'm talking just about the console output (so no high-level) e.g.:

```
std::cout << "\b this is bold";
std::cout << " this is not";
```

I hope there are some libraries, this program is intended for Linux.

Thanks for advises.

Comment: @AlexandruCimpanu, That's not console output.

Comment: I looked at the accepted answer after I red the question: _There is no concept of bold text in C++, there may be in a particular device that displays character text, for example rich-text-format or HTML tagging or a terminal screen. The latter usually involves sending some "escape sequence" relevant to that particular terminal._

Comment: It depends on your terminal/console: the most widely used escape codes are probably those used by [ANSI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code), vt100/220, xterm et al: "\033[1m bold \033[0m not bold".

Comment: Well I remember terminal programs (like in DOS) that are capable to write in bold. Is this because of C/C++ or is there the trick done with Bash/Batch ?

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Comment: thanks @TonyD that's what I'm looking for. On which systems is this working?

Comment: @T.C. it's not necessary to pick one - the question is ultimately about the terminal and pretty much language agnostic; whether the code's `std::cout << "..."` or `printf("...")` isn't a big deal.

Comment: The terminal emulation programs interpret ANSI escape sequences, accordng to the type of terminal they emulate. Some DEC terminals used to be very popular, VT 100,...

Comment: @user3085931: pretty much every terminal/console program that's capable of displaying bold text... some printers might expect you to backspace and print twice to get "bold" output.  If you're using linux/unix, `echo` implementations vary a little bit but you could try `echo -e "\033[1m bold \033[m not bold"` to test it.

Comment: @TonyD well there has to be some kind of criteria: I tried in the Eclipse console it's not working but when I call the program from the linux terminal it's alright.

Comment: @chris: Here you go, I found one duplicate for console output with the answer using VT100 sequences.

Comment: @user3085931: "has to be some kind of criteria" - if you want some ability to detect whether it's supported, I suggest you use ncurses - it utilises a "database" tracking what features are available in thousands of terminals.

Answer (score 0):

That is not a question about C or C++ but rather about your particular console.  Any answer is specific to your target, and possibly in Linux dependent the specific particular terminal emulator.

In most cases a terminal, terminal emulation, or in case of Windows a console window, there will be no support for bold as such - you can often control the colour and brightness of a fixed font however.  You can do this in a number of ways - again platform specific - for example through a library such as curses, by sending terminal specific escape sequences, or in Windows through the Win32 Console API.

Without knowing the specific platform, it is not possible to give a specific answer, and even then that answer may not be portable to other platforms.

Comment: thank you for the answer. In the Top post I said it is intended for a C/C++ program in a console on a linux machine.

Comment: @user3085931 : so you did.  It is always a good idea to establish the environment early in a question - not everyone will read to the bottom! ;-)  In this case it is the most important factor more important that the language.